# What is the right way to set a schedule table?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to build an appointment application with the following tables: `Doctors`, `Schedules`. I'm having a hard time figuring out what the most convenient way is to design the `Schedules` table. Each `doctor` will have it´s own `schedule` so I thought I create a field for the `day` the `doctor`s work and a `start` and `end` dates so I can do math operations within that range.

I'm not going to consider in the application if the doctor is on vacations or at a congress. But I do need to set a time in that range for lunch.

Also if he works only three days a week, how should I handle the days he is off?

```
  create_table "schedules", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "day"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
    t.integer  "doctor_id"
    t.time     "start_time"
    t.time     "end_time"
  end
```

Comment: Thank you sawa and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have IDs for each Doctor in both tables and have the numeric values for the days.

The structure should be like the following;

```
Doctors Table
---------------------------------------------
Doctor_ID | Doctor_name | Practice | etc
---------------------------------------------

Schedules
-----------------------------------------------------------
Day_ID    | Time (hour,minute,second) | Doctor_ID | Istaken
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Istaken will be a bool variable which will tell you if the hour of the day is taken or not. What you will need to do is , you will need to create 24 table for each day and for each doctor if you do not want to add new variables each time.

Or what you can do is;

Add the 24 hour as columns, such as hourone | hourtwo etc and list them as 0 or 1. This way you will be saved from adding new records each time.

If you create it this way, it will be easier on the system to search through the tables since you will be joining integer values on Doctor_ID

Comment: I agree on the Day_id, but  only one field for the hour of the appointment? does that mean I have to create a record for every appointment the doctor can  work?

Comment: you can create 24 hours for all of them and then add another boolean column to determine if the hour is full or not.

Comment: 24 table for each day and for each doctor, you mean records right?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to decide the smallest piece in the schedule. The common sense is "hour", or you can use "day" or "half day" as you like. Once defined, it's hard to change.

The schedule table will have following main elements:

`id`#the unique id

`start_time` #This is very important. It present each working hours' start time for querying from calendar. Better to use hex datatime stamp.

`doctor_id` #The doctor who occupy this hour. If not occupied, it's blank. Note you may have two doctors occupy the same hour. So, either `start_time` or `doctor_id` is not unique, but combined together they are unique.

`patient_id` #The patient who ordered this hour.

`description` #Description of this

Now comes the use case:

In you calendar, for a given day, you show 8 hours available. You query the db to find if any schedule is on the starting time of each hour, if exists, you mark this hour and link to the schedule.

Note there may be a case that a patient asks for several consecutive hours of a doctor. For example 3 hours, in this case you need to add three records to schedule table, with difference on only `id` and `start_time`.

There may also be case that two doctors scheduled at the same hour. It's easy to display as the above scheme.

The arragement should work. Hope it helps.